# Importing Excel list where every cell is a individual List python, 2d to 3d list

Tags: python, csv, 3d, 2d, import-csv

I have a CSV Excel file with a lot of rows. When I import it with csv.reader it converts it into a 2D-List where every Row is a single list. How do you break open those and convert every cell to a single list.

My Input:

```
[['1;2;3'],['Hello;How;areyou'],['test;1;2'],['4;5;6']]
```

aspired output:

```
[[[1],[2],[3]],[[Hello],[How],[areyou]],[[test],[1],[2]],[[4],[5],[6]]]
```

sorry if this question has been asked a lot, but i dont really find a solution for me.

Edit:
There is something else I didnt notice when I looked in at the output.
It is a 2D list and the items in the nested list are saved between highcommata like: [['1;2;3']]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if your lists there are lists or strings since you have semi-columns delimiting them. Under the assumption they are a string you can use

```py
example = ["1;2;3","Hello;How;areyou","test;1;2","4;5;6"]
desired = [[[elm] for elm in l.split(';')] for l in example]
```

```
>>> [[['1'], ['2'], ['3']],
 [['Hello'], ['How'], ['areyou']],
 [['test'], ['1'], ['2']],
 [['4'], ['5'], ['6']]]
```

if they are in fact 2d lists then the following gives what you want I think

```py
example = [[1,2,3],["Hello","How","areyou"],["test",1,2],[4,5,6]]
desired = [[[elm] for elm in lst] for lst in example]
```

```
>>> [[[1], [2], [3]],
 [['Hello'], ['How'], ['areyou']],
 [['test'], [1], [2]],
 [[4], [5], [6]]]
```

have a read of https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension for some more examples of list comprehension to get these kind of results

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. The listitems in the list are somehow seperated by semicolons. After printing the input it looks exactly like this:

Comment: [['1;2;3'],['Hello;How;areyou'],['test;1;2'],['4;5;6']]

Comment: hey it worked, thanks a lot! I had to change the delimiter to delimit it by ; and then i could use ur code line. Could you explain how this code of yours worked? @Richard Boyne